# How can I develop and publish a game when I don't have the money to buy a brand new computer?

Tags: unity, publishing

I'd like to complete and publish a game made with Unity, but given the fact that the cost of a brand new computer represents a *significant* part of my yearly income, I don't have enough money to buy one.

My ultimate goal is to publish the game on iOS.

Aside from generating more revenue upfront, what are my options?

---

**Notes from the moderators:** We've made this question canonical, so we're looking for non-specific options (e.g. please avoid targeting specific regions, or suggesting to buy specific models, etc.); we'd like to help future visitors coming from all over the world, for the years to come.

Comment: I've made this question more generic, in the hopes that future visitors will also find it useful. Please avoid being too specific. And if you guys feel like closing it again, please go ahead, we will not re-open it.

Comment: Try used hardware.

Comment: And please avoid writing answers in comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple options:

- Go big, but start small: You could save up for a used Windows computer, finish your game, publish it on Google Play, generate revenue from it, and use that revenue to buy a used Mac computer, then publish your game for iOS. Making games is fun, but if you spend more money on it than you make out of it, really, it's a hobby.
- If you have friends that do own a Mac, you can ask *them* to build publish your game on the iOS App Store for you.
- Another option would be to look for a [games incubator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_incubator). This is a company that has office space, infrastructure and support for other small companies to get going in game development. They help getting your first game out.